# Is there a way that can programmatically fix JSON syntax error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

My function receives a JSON string that may have syntax error, how can I fix the error in my function so that I can call `JSON.parse()`?

Question story: I want to parse the command output of `sudo lshw -class network -json` which is a linux command. For example, the PC has 2 NICs, so the command output has 2 JSON objects. An exmpale is as following:

```
{
    "businfo" : "pci@0000:01:00.0",
    some other keys
}
{
    "businfo" : "usb@1:4",
    some other keys
}
```

NOTE: the 2 objects has no "," seperator. So `JSON.parse()` will generate error.

ODD: another hyper-v vm's lshw has the same version as used above, but it can generate correct JSON with "," between 2 objects. Same command line.

Answer (score 1):

IF the only problem is that there is no comma between the objects and the format of the string is the same you can do string replace for  '} {' to '}, {', and then the resulting string should be parseable.
Hope that would help.

Comment: another question: there are unexpectable number of spaces between "}" and "{", how to add the ","... I think the problem may be narrowed to: how to use regular expression to replace "}any number of spaces and \n{" with "},{".

Comment: Here is the very simple method to do it var str = "{object one}     {object two} {object three}"; 
var res = str.replace(/}\s*{/g,'},{');